# ngx-toaster message is taking time to display in browser 30-40 seconds in angular 11

Tags: angular, performance, ngx-toastr

In App.module:
import ToastrModule in appModule

```
ToastrModule.forRoot({
  timeOut: 3000,
  preventDuplicates: true,
}),
```

In inner component

```
this.toastr.error("test err");
```

it is taking time to display, arount 30 to 40 sec.

Comment: Could you please replicate it in a stackblitz demo app? Not enough information to help you.

Comment: Please, replicate it in Stackblitz or share a repo where we can replicate that behavior.

Comment: it is working fine when I have create a demo application.  It is not can be regenerate in demo app or in stackblitz.

Comment: Even It is taking time on OnInit as well. after display the toastr message it is not closing it self. even i have added  timeOut: 3000, I need to close it manually.

Comment: Your shared code seems to be working fine, something else might be interferering with your toastr.

Comment: I got the issue, and resolved it,  AfterContentChecked hook performing operation on few controls. so it was delay the toaster.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to configure the time Toaster message displays using the following configuration

```
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    .....
  ],
  imports: [
    ....,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({ timeOut: 7500, 
                           extendedTimeOut: 7500, 
                           preventDuplicates: true })
  ],
})
```

- timeOut - toast time to live in milliseconds default: 5000
- extendedTimeOut - time to close after a user hovers over toast default: 1000